# Why json data is lost and repeats from the beginning during the PHP input process?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Have PHP Script Like This:

```
$current_data = file_get_contents('data/api.json');  
        $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
        $extra = array('id' => $_GET['id'], 'name' => 'SIMONE', 'talktime' : '2023-09-08 00:00:10');  
        $array_data[] = $extra;  
        $final_data = json_encode($array_data); 
        if(file_put_contents('data/api.json', $final_data))  
        {  
             $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";  
        }
```

The script can run properly, and data can be inputted in json. But why json data is lost and repeats from the beginning during the PHP input process after after a few rows?

example:

```
[{"id":"00001","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 00:00:10"},
{"id":"00002","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 00:01:02"},{"id":"00003","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 00:03:02"},
...
{"id":"04023","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 04:30:22"}]
```

after few moment, that data lost and repeats from the beginning like this:

```
[{"id":"04024","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 04:32:10"},
{"id":"04025","name":"SIMONE","talktime":"2023-09-08 04:35:08"}]
```

is there something wrong? please help, and thank you..

JSON DATA REPEAT FROM BEGINNING WITH INSERT PHP

Comment: Please indent your code. It's not at all readable right now.

Comment: you should check the return of `file_get_contents('data/api.json')` before going any further. If that fails but the overwrite of the file succeeds it could reset the file. I think it would depend on PHP versions as to whether it threw an error. In any case you need to add diagnostics to find out what is failing.

Comment: "you should check the return of file_get_contents('data/api.json') before going any further" 

Ooooh i see, thanks for your answers and suggestions...